# Checking Active Directory Expire Dates

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal

I have a program that runs some validations on objects in active directory and one of my checks is to see if the expiry date is set within a year.  With a `UserPrincipal` object I can check the `.AccountExpirationDate` date to see if it has one but how would I look at that date to see if it's set to expire within a year?

This is currently what I'm rolling with

```
protected Check AccountExpiresMandatoryCheck = new Check()
{
    ResultMessageTemplate = "User(s) don't have an expiry date or expiry date is greater than 1 year",
    Run = delegate(Principal principal, AccountPoint point)
    {
        UserPrincipal user = principal as UserPrincipal;
        if (user == null) return false;
        return user.AccountExpirationDate != null || //check here if the date is a year or less;
    }
};
```

I realize stuff like a `Check` and `AccountPoint` are custom objects made by me but I'm hoping that won't prevent anyone from answering my question of;

> How would I check if the expiry date was set to be a year or less

Comment: Are you trying to see if the date is within one year of the current date, or if the expiration date was set a year away from the day it was created?

Comment: @efischency I'm thinking the second one.

Comment: I don't think you are going to get what you are looking for then.  Mostly due to the fact that I am guessing your sysadmin could change that expiration date, and without tracking all of the changes how would you know what it was initially set to?

Comment: @efischency that's what I was worried about.  Hmmm... what to do then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tough to tell exactly what you're after, but this may help.

```
DateTime oneYearAgoToday = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
return user.AccountExpirationDate != null || user.AccountExpirationDate > oneYearAgoToday;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but comparing to today's date doesn't really help me see the length of the expiry.  If someone were to go and increase the expiry by less than a year so it's still within the year then I don't think this would pick that up.  Although something is better than nothing so I'll consider it.

Comment: I guess for my purposes this actually does do what I want it to.  A user's account at any point in the year should never be greater than a year.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check the difference from current date and see if the expiration days is less than 365 or against any reference date that you want. But you can get all sort of values from the difference and compare against that

```
var dateDifference = theUser.AccountExpirationDate - DateTime.Now;
if (dateDifference != null)
    Debug.WriteLine(dateDifference.Value.Days);
```

Comment: But there's no way to get the date the expiry was set in active directory is there?

Comment: well if you are looking for that then I don't think we can get that. That is kind of logging details that you are looking at.

Comment: And the problem is that is never logged so I think I'm out of luck.